# First Flask unittest is successful, all subsequent tests fail. Maybe a stale app_context?

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, python-unittest

I'm trying to get some unit tests setup using the Python unittest module, but I cannot get more than one test to pass. They seem to run them in alphabetical order and only the first one completes successfully. I can run any one test individually, though, and it completes fine. I'm guessing it has something to do with not having a fresh app_context each time, but I can't figure it out.

```
❯ ./test_api.py
.FF
======================================================================
FAIL: test_get_category_of_questions (__main__.TriviaTestCase)
Test getting a list of trivia questions by category.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test_api.py", line 73, in test_get_category_of_questions
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
AssertionError: 404 != 200

======================================================================
FAIL: test_get_one_question (__main__.TriviaTestCase)
Test getting a specific question.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test_api.py", line 35, in test_get_one_question
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
AssertionError: 404 != 200

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in 0.343s

FAILED (failures=2)
[1]    3318 exit 1     ./test_api.py
```

The last two 404s should be 200s. There might be a clue in the fact that I'm not even getting the expected 404s. There should be some json attached to the response body, but there is not and the mimetype is actually ['text/html']. I'm completely confused and not sure at all how to proceed. I would switch to pytest which I've had better luck with, but this project requires the use of unittest.

https://github.com/matthew02/FSND_TriviaAPI/blob/master/backend/test_api.py

https://github.com/matthew02/FSND_TriviaAPI

Comment: You need to show some code.

Comment: Just added the links. Sorry about that.

Comment: The debugger didn't inform me of anything useful. Each test has a unique `app_context` and `test_client`. I'm still at a loss as to what is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it to work. I had to create the Flask app only once as a class attribute rather than creating a new app each time in `setUp()`. Then I created a new `test_client()` in `setUp()` and I was able to use that client to make requests. Thanks to everyone who looked into it with me.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation here:

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/testing/

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/

It seems that you must either close your connection, or enclose your `test_client()` in a `with` block to defer it. Something like:

```
with self.app.test_client() as client:
    response = client.get('/questions')
    print(f'test_get_default_page_of_questions response is {response}')
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

Comment: I've tried some variations of the `with` block including just now trying the way you posted, but unfortunately I get the exact same result.